# How to access Android Service Mode from your application source code

Tags: android

I am wondering, is there any method from which we can access the content of the service mode in android cell phone (which we get after dialing *#*#197328640#*#* in the dialer) from our source code? if so tell me how can i retrieve them? i want to take the information of GSM related stuff in my coding, which is available in the service mode of android...

Comment: means you want access service mode in your app and dial a number  ##197328640##  or get result back in your app without user interaction?

Comment: Try logging what happens when you enter that number. There is probably an Intent you can start yourself from code.

Comment: I think that code may be manufacturer or model specific, as I get "Invalid request" when I put it into my phone.  You need to determine what specific pieces of information you need and try to find out how to access them.

Comment: @ imran... what i want is that, is there any method i can access information from service mode? and take it to the code... if so then how!

Comment: @ zapl... thats a good idea, i will try that for sure...

Comment: your question is not cleared to me, what you want to get and how? Elaborate your question and make it clear so anybody can provide solution of your problem.

Comment: @Aleks G... sorry buddy the code is *#*#197328640#*#* and it is independent of any model